# How to escape apostrophe in nagios contacts config file

Tags: nagios

There is a user with apostrophe in their name. 
Nagios documentation says that semicolon, apostrophes and quotation marks should be avoided but it doesn't provide info about how to escape one if it is name.

I have tried `\'` , `\\'`, `"someo'name"`, `"someo\'name"` etc but nagios checkconfig fails every time.

Please let me know what else I need to do.

Comment: Is it so important to use that name with apostrophe?

Comment: Yeah, person is higher up in the command chain and they want alerts.   
I suggested  to use email alias and also swap apostrophe with hyphen  but would really like to fix apostrophe issue.

Comment: Maybe this is what you need - https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/configmain.html?#illegal_object_name_chars